# how identify a textbox for 2 form in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a text box in a form in c#.now I want to this text box will be identified to another form,for example form 2.because I want to use the text box in next form.
what should I do?

Comment: Did you try to just call Form1.textBox1.Text = 'Hello world';

Comment: Go in the designer cs file and ensure the textbox is marked public, then you should be able to access it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only concerned about `Text` property then instead of exposing `TextBox` as public from your form, create a string property which would expose the `Text` property from that form.

```
public string TextBoxText
{
    get
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        textBox1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

If you are going to access other properties of the `TextBox`, then you have to mark it as `public` in designer.cs file.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying *designer.cs* which can be harmful, you can expose `TextBox` text or even TextBox control by making its *public property*. Following example exposes `Text` property.

**Form1:**

```
public string TextBoxABCText { 
    get { return YourTextBoxName.Text; }
    set { YourTextBoxName.Text = value; }
}
```

**Form2:**

```
Form1 frm1;

public Form2(Form1 frm1){
    this.frm1 = frm1;
}

private void YourFunction(){
    string strText = this.frm1.TextBoxABCText;
}
```

Comment: I wrote that,but still textbox1.text is unkown in form2:-(

Comment: Access _form1's_ object reference in _form2_, for example by passing in _form2's_ constructor then use this reference to get _textbox1's_ text, see the edit.